# How can I make VS Code restore its windows to the virtual desktops they were previously in upon reopening?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using macOS 11.6. After restarting VS Code, the VS Code windows all open on the same desktop (even though they were open on different desktops before)! When I do the same operation in the Sublime Text editor, there is no problem. How can I make all VS Code windows open on their current desktop after restart?

I looked in the VS Code settings but couldn't find a relevant option. I was expecting all the windows to open on their desktops, but again they all opened on a single desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This is the subject of an open feature-request (not sure if the feature-request is specific to the Windows OS, but I don't think it is): [VSCode windows not staying in their respective virtual desktops on app restart #146915](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146915). Give it a thumbs up to show support for it and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump".

<sup>There's a macOS-specific one, but it got closed as a duplicate (of what it is a duplicate is not clear to me): [Reopen VSCode windows to previous desktops/workspaces on macOS on login #45737](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45737). There's also an explicitly-Windows-specific one that's also still open: [Support virtual desktops on windows #152869](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152869).</sup>

According to the VS Code maintainers ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146915#issuecomment-1756845851)), the feature is blocked on the following enhancement requests for Electron: [Add workspace API #5362](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5362) and [[Feature Request]: Enable Application Window Restoration #37494](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/37494). You should probably give those thumbs ups as well.

Your your reference / learning purposes, I found these issue tickets by googling "`github vscode issues reopen virtual desktop`".

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find any answer to my question in the github issues.

Comment: @AyhanKesicioglu the answer is to wait and show your support for them by giving them a thumbs up. if there was a workaround in those issue tickets, I'd have mentioned it in my answer post in accordance with https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425696/11107541.